# PHP file includes inside function, need to retain global variables. (Trying to wrap HTML comments)

Tags: php

In an attempt to speed up my workflow and help the back end guys with integration (I'm a front end dev) I'm attempting to extend the file includes function by wrapping comments around each file include to output it's filename:

```
function include_module($path) {
    echo "\n\n<!-- MODULE: ".basename($path, '.php')." -->\n";
    include($path);
    echo "\n<!-- /MODULE: ".basename($path, '.php')." -->\n\n";
}   
include_module('form-controls.php');
```

However this results in the loss of access to any variables set outside the function. I know I can do:

```
global $var
```

But that will only give me access to $var (I'm aware I could do $var['var1'], etc), is there any way to do 'global all' or can anyone think of a different approach to wrap the comments?

Cheers :)

Comment: You could pass `$GLOBALS` as an argument... but youll still need to access it with an array from within the function unless you call `extract()`. None of thats probably a good idea...

Comment: @prodigitalson no need to ever pass any of the superglobals as an argument, they are accessible in any scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function include_module($path) {
    foreach($GLOBALS as $name => $value) global $$name;
    echo "\n\n<!-- MODULE: ".basename($path, '.php')." -->\n";
    include($path);
    echo "\n<!-- /MODULE: ".basename($path, '.php')." -->\n\n";
}   
include_module('form-controls.php');
```

Comment: This works for existent variables but all variables declared inside your included files won't be global anymore, they will be local to the include_module() function which is most likely NOT what you need

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following to access the globals.

```
extract($GLOBALS, EXTR_REFS);
```